# rails paperclip batch processing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

How can I use paperclip to move files uploaded using ftp to a server, create thumbnails and then move it all to aws?

Using paperclip as part of an upload process is no problem, and moving the files to aws as part of that process is also no big problem, but how can I use paperclip as part of something running entirely using cron and rake?

Answer (score 0):

http://codewordstudios.com/posts/3-delayed-upload-delivery-to-s3-with-paperclip-delayed-job

In rake you can require the rails environment with `task :yourtask => :environment`.

If you're trying to do so in a way which doesn't touch a database then you might need to look into creating your own Paperclip::Attachment instances and dealing with their events directly. (I'm not entirely the expert on how you'd do that.)

http://rdoc.info/github/thoughtbot/paperclip#

Perhaps you could elaborate on exactly what you'd like to happen and what solutions you would not like.